# CARD of typedef of 0 to 7 nat

Tags: isabelle

## Update 2 (151015)

I put some source below. It shows a skeleton of what I may use.

With some help, I'm getting more sophisticated. I now know the difference between a numeral type type, and a constant of type numeral. The notation is all the same, and I'm used to using functions that operate on terms, not types. With `CARD`, that changes the paradigm some.

As far as numeral type notation, even with `show_consts`, it's not obvious that I'm looking at a type or a term. So, I draw off always using `show_sorts` and `show_consts`. A 0-ary type constructor type, like `nat`, never gets annotated with anything. Knowing that helps.

I said that a certain theorem wasn't being proved by magic without not importing `Numeral_Type`, but that's not true.

Succinct syntax is important, so getting good type inference is important. It looks like I get good type inference when using the numeral type.

From the answer, I also got my first use of using a dummy type, which, at this point, appears to be a much better way to do things.

Here's some source:

```
theory i151013c_numeral_has_type_enforcement
imports Complex_Main "~~/src/HOL/Library/Numeral_Type"
begin
declare [[show_sorts, show_consts]]

datatype ('a,'size) vD = vC "'a list"

definition CARD_foo :: "('a,'s::{finite,card_UNIV}) vD => ('a,'s) vD => nat" 
  where
  "CARD_foo x y = card (UNIV :: 's set)" 

notation (input) vC ("vC|_" [1000] 1000)      
notation (output) vC ("vC|_" [1000] 999)

value "CARD_foo (vC|x::(nat,32) vD) vC|y = (32::nat)"  (*True*)
value "CARD_foo (vC|x::(nat,65536) vD) vC|y = 65536"   (*True*)

type_synonym nv3 = "(nat, 3) vD"
notation CARD_foo (infixl "*+*" 65)

value "vC|m *+* (vC|n::nv3) = 3"     (*True*)

type_notation (input) vD ("< _ , _ >")

term "x::<'a,'s::{finite,card_UNIV}>"    
term "vC|m *+* (vC|n::<'a,64>) = 64"
value "vC|m *+* (vC|n::<'a,64>) = 64" (*True*)

(*Next, Am I adding 2 types of type numeral? Or am I adding 2 constants of 
  type numeral, which produces a numeral type? The notation for numeral types 
  and numeral type constants is identical.*)
value "vC|[3] *+* (vC|y::<nat,2 + 3>)"
term  "vC|[3] *+* (vC|y::<nat,2 + 3>)"

(*I guess 2 and 3 are types. In the output panel, 0-ary types, such as 'nat',
  don't get annotated with anything, where nat constants do.*)
lemma "vC|[3] *+* (vC|y::<nat,2 + 3>) = 5"
  by(simp add: CARD_foo_def)

(*Type error clash. Oh well. Just don't do that.*)
term  "(vC|x::<'a,5>) *+* (vC|y::<'a,2 + 3>)"

definition vCARD :: "('a, 's::{finite,card_UNIV}) vD => nat" where
  "vCARD x = CARD('s)"
declare vCARD_def [simp add]
lemma 
  "vCARD(x::<'a,'s::{finite,card_UNIV}>) = 
   vCARD(y::<'b,'s::{finite,card_UNIV}>)"
by(simp)

end
```

## Update (151014)

Here I explain to M.Eberl why I don't use the numeral type, based upon what I know and have experienced.

#### Related comment about `typedef` and a past question

A while back, I got exposed to `~~/src/HOL/Library/Cardinality`, along with `Numeral_Type` from this answer by M.Eberl:

- [Trying to generalize a bit vector that uses typedef, bool list, and nat length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415275/trying-to-generalize-a-bit-vector-that-uses-typedef-bool-list-and-nat-length)

That question was also related to `typedef`. Partly from my experiments at that time, I try to stay away from `typedef,` and use the magic that comes with `datatype`.

Even today, I started having problems with the `sz8` `typedef` not working with `value`, because of abstraction problems. After looking back at the answer linked to above, it partially shows what has to be done to get `typedef` working with `value`. I have a `size8` in the new source I include that shows what I did. I think there's a problem with the `equal` function, that it needs to be fixed similar to what's shown in the answer above.

#### An Example size datatype and vector datatype

Now, I make a few comments about the two example `datatype`s in the second source I include below.

The use case for a size type is for vector length, where the vectors are lists.

The size type enforces that for a binary operation, two vectors have the same length. I then only have to check that the two vectors actually are the right length.

The problem with the numeral type is that there's no type enforcement. My example function has the following signature, with the `datatype` shown:

```
datatype ('a,'size) vD = vC "'a list" 'size

CARD_foo :: "(nat,'s::card_UNIV) vD => (nat,'s) vD => nat"
```

But I can to this:

```
term "CARD_foo (vC [] 10) (vC [] 11)"
```

Other comments are in the source. I have a `typedef size8` at the end, and I don't know, at this time, how to fix that.

Though there's no type enforcement with the numeral type, I guess I can depend on type size using `CARD`, based on this:

```
theorem CARD_of_type_of_terms_of_same_type_are_equal:
  "CARD_foo (vC n size1term) = CARD_foo (vC m size2term)"
unfolding CARD_foo_def
by(auto simp add: CARD_foo_def)
```

To get that by magic, I had to not import `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Numeral_Type"`.

Thanks for the help. It's invaluable, and thanks for how to get the proofs I asked for originally. It helps to learn things here and there about `typedef`.

#### The new example source:

```
theory i151013b_2nd
imports Complex_Main  (*"$GEZ/e/IsE"*)
        "~~/src/HOL/Library/Cardinality" "~~/src/HOL/Library/Numeral_Type"
begin
declare [[show_sorts, show_consts]]

(*::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*)                   
(*::¦ NUMERAL TYPE DOESN'T GUARANTEE TYPE ENFORCEMENT FOR A BINARY OP ¦:::*)

(*----------------------------*)
(*The size type as a datatype.*)
datatype sz8D = sz8C bool bool bool

(*-----------------------------------*)
(*Typdef 'n <= 7 would be preferable.*)    
lemma UNIV_sz8D:
  "UNIV = 
  {sz8C False False False, sz8C False False True,  sz8C False True  False, 
   sz8C False True  True,  sz8C True  False False, sz8C True  False True, 
   sz8C True  True  False, sz8C True  True  True}"
by(auto, metis (full_types) sz8D.exhaust)

lemma card_UNIV_sz8D [simp]: "card (UNIV :: sz8D set) = 8" 
  by(unfold UNIV_sz8D, auto)

instantiation sz8D :: card_UNIV 
begin
  definition "finite_UNIV = Phantom(sz8D) True"
  definition "card_UNIV = Phantom(sz8D) 8"      
instance
  apply(default)
  unfolding UNIV_sz8D finite_UNIV_sz8D_def card_UNIV_sz8D_def 
  by(auto)
end

(*-----------------------------------------*)
(*The vector type with an example function.*)
datatype ('a,'size) vD = vC "'a list" 'size

definition CARD_foo :: "(nat,'s::card_UNIV) vD => (nat,'s) vD => nat" where
  "CARD_foo x y = card (UNIV :: 's set)" 
thm CARD_foo_def

(*--------------------------------------------------------*)
(*sz8D: Size enforcement. Error if I mix other size types.*)
value "CARD_foo (vC [] (s::sz8D)) (vC [1] (t::sz8D))" (*outputs 8*)
value "CARD_foo (vC [] (sz8C False False False)) (vC [1] (t::sz8D))"

(*-------------------------------------*)
(*numeral: No enforcement of size type.*)
term "CARD_foo (vC [] 10) (vC [] 11)" (* 
  "CARD_foo (vC [] (10::'a::{card_UNIV,numeral})) 
            (vC [] (11::'a::{card_UNIV,numeral}))" :: "nat" *)

(*Can't eval the type to nat, even if they're the same*)
value "CARD_foo (vC [] 10) (vC [] 10)"

(*But here, CARDs are different anyway; no enforcement, no value.*)
value "CARD_foo (vC [] 10) (vC [] 11)" (*
  "of_phantom card_UNIV_class.card_UNIV" :: "nat"*)
lemma "CARD_foo (vC [] 10) (vC [] 11) = z" oops (*
   show_consts:
   CARD_foo (vC [] (10::'a)) (vC [] (11::'a)) = z 
   'a :: {card_UNIV,numeral} *)

(*Can evaluate when there's not a conflict.*)
term "CARD(10)"
value "CARD(10)"              (*outputs 10*)
lemma "CARD(10) = 10" by simp (*show_consts: 'UNIV :: 10 set'*)
value "CARD(11)"              (*outputs 11*)

(*No eval if CARD('a) is used in a function.*)
definition fooID :: "'a::card_UNIV => nat" where 
  "fooID x = CARD('a)"
term "fooID(5)"
value "fooID(5)"

(*::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*)          
(*::¦ HOWEVER, BY FUNCTION UNIQUENESS, I SUPPOSE THERE'S NO AMBIGUITY ¦:::*)

(*[>) I have to drop down to only 'src/HOL/Library/Cardinality' to get this. 
  [>) For some reason, it won't unfold the definition.*)
theorem CARD_of_type_of_terms_of_same_type_are_equal:
  "CARD_foo (vC n size_1term) = CARD_foo (vC m size_2term)"
unfolding CARD_foo_def
by(auto simp add: CARD_foo_def)

(*::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*)          
(*::¦ CAN'T USE TYPEDEF AFTERALL IF I CAN'T FIX THIS ¦::::::::::::::::::::*)

(*NOTE ABOUT PLUG'N'PLAY:
  [>) See http://stackoverflow.com/q/27415275
  [>) 'value' for 'CARD_foo' needs class 'equal'
  [>) '[code abstract]' didn't work, so I used '[code]'.*)

typedef size8 = "{n::nat. n ≤ 7}"
  morphisms size8_to_nat Abs_size8
  by(blast)

definition nat_to_size8 :: "nat => size8" where
  "nat_to_size8 n == if n ≤ 7 then Abs_size8 n else Abs_size8 0"

lemma nat_to_size8_code [code]:
  "size8_to_nat (nat_to_size8 n) = (if n ≤ 7 then n else 0)"
unfolding nat_to_size8_def
by(simp add: Abs_size8_inverse)

setup_lifting type_definition_size8
instantiation size8 :: equal
begin
  lift_definition equal_size8 :: "size8 => size8 => bool" is "λx y. x = y" .
  instance 
    by(default, transfer, auto simp add: equal_size8_def)
end

instantiation size8 :: card_UNIV 
begin
  definition "finite_UNIV = Phantom(size8) True"
  definition "card_UNIV = Phantom(size8) 8"
  instance sorry
end

value "CARD_foo (vC [] (Abs_size8 0)) (vC [] (Abs_size8 0))" (*
   Abstraction violation: constant Abs_size8 *)

end
```

## Original Question

I'm using `typedef` to define some types that are used as size types, to be used like this: `CARD(sz8)`. I can use `datatype`, but it takes a lot longer for it to set itself up.

I guess I don't understand how to show two values are unique with the inverse theorems generated by `typedef` for `sz8`.

I have my type, `sz8`, and I instantiate it as `card_UNIV`. What's incomplete is my theorem `card_UNIV_sz8`, which is `"card (UNIV::sz8 set) = 8"`.

```
theory i151013a
imports Complex_Main "~~/src/HOL/Library/Cardinality" 
  "$GEZ/e/IsE"
begin
declare [[show_sorts, show_consts]]


typedef sz8 = "{n::nat. n ≤ 7}"
  by(blast)


theorem UNIV_sz8:
  "UNIV = {s::sz8. ∃n. n ≤ 7 ∧ s = Abs_sz8 n}"
  using Rep_sz8 Rep_sz8_inverse
by(fastforce)


theorem foo1:
  assumes "Abs_sz8 n ∈ {s::sz8. ∃n ≤ 7. s = Abs_sz8 n}"
  shows "n ∈ {n. n ≤ 7}"
proof
  fix n :: nat
  note assms
  obtain n1 where 
    f1: "n1 ≤ (7::nat) ∧ Abs_sz8 n = Abs_sz8 n1"
    using Rep_sz8 Rep_sz8_inverse 
    by(fastforce)
  hence "n = n1"

  oops

find_theorems name: "sz8"


instance sz8 :: finite
  apply default
  unfolding UNIV_sz8
  by(simp)

theorem card_UNIV_sz8 [simp]:
  "card (UNIV::sz8 set) = 8"
unfolding UNIV_sz8
sorry


instantiation sz8 :: card_UNIV
begin
  definition "finite_UNIV = Phantom(sz8) True"
  definition "card_UNIV = Phantom(sz8) 8"

  instance
    apply default
    unfolding finite_UNIV_sz8_def card_UNIV_sz8_def
  by(simp_all)
end

end
```

Comment: Note that the `+` that you use when you write the type `2 + 3` is the sum type from `~~/src/HOL/Sum_Type.thy`. It is /not/ some kind of addition on numeral types, and while the type `2 + 3` does have 5 elements (`Inl 0`, `Inl 1`, `Inr 0`, `Inr 1`, `Inr 2`) and is in fact isomorphic to the numeral type `5`, it is not the same type. That is why type inference fails.

Comment: @Manuel, thanks for the info. I looked at Ch.14 of the HOL PDF. More to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The answer to your question

First of all: I will answer your question, but then I will tell you why what you are doing is unnecessary.

You can show the distinctness of the values using the theorem `sz8.Abs_sz8_inject`, which shows up if you do `find_theorems Abs_sz8`:

```
(?x::nat) ∈ {n::nat. n ≤ (7::nat)} ⟹
(?y::nat) ∈ {n::nat. n ≤ (7::nat)} ⟹
(Abs_sz8 ?x = Abs_sz8 ?y) = (?x = ?y)
```

You can prove your theorem e.g. like this:

```
lemma sz8_image: "x ∈ Abs_sz8 ` {0..7}" 
  by (cases x rule: sz8.Abs_sz8_cases) auto

theorem card_UNIV_sz8 [simp]: "card (UNIV::sz8 set) = 8"
proof -
  from sz8_image have "UNIV = Abs_sz8 ` {0..7}" by blast
  also from sz8.Abs_sz8_inject have "card … = card {0..(7::nat)}"
    by (intro card_image inj_onI) simp_all
  finally show ?thesis by simp
qed
```

## What you should do instead

Have a look at the theory `~~/src/HOL/Library/Numeral_Type`, where `~~` stands for the Isabelle root directory.

This defines a type `n` for every positive integer `n`, which contains exactly the numbers from `0` to `n - 1` and even defines lots of typeclass instances and modular arithmetic on them. For example:

```
value "(2 - 5 :: 10) = 7"
> "True" :: "bool"
```

This is probably exactly what you want and it comes fully set up; doing all of this by hand is quite tedious, and if you ever need a size 16 type, you have to do the same thing all over again.

## Update: More on numeral types

In your updated question, you claim that type checking for numeral types does not work. That is not correct; the problem is merely that the 10 in your `vC [] 10` has no meaning. Your intention was probably to specify that the length parameter `'size` in the type of that function must be 10.

However, *every* numeral type contains a 10. For instance, `(10 :: 5) = 0` and `(10 :: 6) = 4`. Therefore, the 10 and 11 in there do not cause any type restrictions at all.

What you have to do is constrain `'size` at the type level:

```
datatype ('a,'size) vD = vC "'a list"

consts CARD_foo :: "(nat,'s::card_UNIV) vD => (nat,'s) vD => nat"

term "CARD_foo (vC [] :: (nat, 10) vD) (vC [] :: (nat, 11) vD)"
(* Type error *)
```

If you really want to do something on the value-level similar to what you tried to do, you can use the following trick:

```
datatype ('a,'size) vD = vC "'a list" "'size itself"

consts CARD_foo :: "(nat,'s::card_UNIV) vD => (nat,'s) vD => nat"

term "CARD_foo (vC [] TYPE(10)) (vC [] TYPE(11))"
```

`'a itself` is basically a singleton type that contains the value `TYPE('a)`. I think the variant without these `itself` values is probably more convenient in the long run though.

As for why your `CARD_of_type_of_terms_of_same_type_are_equal` does not work, I cannot say without seeing the definition of the constants involved, I am quite sure that everything that works with your hand-crafted `sz8` type will work with numeral types.

At the end of the day, you can always replace `sz8` everywhere in your code with `8` and everything should still work.

Comment: Manual, I explain in an updated answer why I don't use the numeral type. I also show that I have things I need to fix to be able to use the typedef size. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer and commented some more on this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I showed my simplified way of doing things based on your answer.